# Running Ruby 1.9.3 in Powershell ISE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, powershell

I am having trouble running Ruby in Powershell after upgrading to ISE.

Ruby works fine in Command Prompt with path:

```
C:\Ruby193\bun> .\irb
```

In ISE this causes a new window to briefly flash open and then disappear, then at the the bottom it stalls saying:

```
"Running script / selection. Press Ctrl+Break to stop."
```

Answer (score 1):

IRB is an interactive application, right? It's probably not supported to run IRB inside of the PowerShell ISE, due to that fact. The reason that you're seeing the "Running script" text is because IRB is hanging inside of the PowerShell ISE, and blocking execution.

Microsoft included a built-in variable called `$psUnsupportedConsoleApplications` inside of PowerShell ISE, but of course did not include `irb.exe` in that list, because it's not a native Windows executable.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, so can I not run IRB in Powershell ISE? It worked just fine in my older version of Powershell.

Advice for alternatives (with easy set-up)? Looking for something that allows tabbed windows.

Comment: Yeah, I believe you are SOL with running IRB in the PowerShell ISE. As an example, try to launch `nslookup` in ISE, and see what it says. Interactive command line apps just aren't supported in ISE.

Comment: Aaack, so it works ok on the older version of Powershell? 

Advice for alternatives (with easy set-up)? Looking for something that allows tabbed windows.